# Is there a way to specify supported submit methods in swagger jaxrs doclet?

Tags: jax-rs, swagger, documentation-generation, swagger-ui, doclet

I have a restservice, I need to expose to my customers. The documentation is done by [Swagger-jaxrs-doclet](https://github.com/ryankennedy/swagger-jaxrs-doclet). It works as I want it to, but I don't want to let my customers sent requests to my services via the API. The reason is quiet simple, I don't want them to mess up my backend. Swagger has the possibility to set `supportedSubmitMethods`. It is not absolutely safe, but it is a start. Is there a way to set the `supportedSubmitMethods` for Swagger-jaxrs-doclet?